# get the max record out of a google big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with 198Mil records.

I am using this query to get the LATEST records for each ID:

```
with cte as (
select *, row_number() OVER (Partition by ATTOM_ID ORDER BY LastLoadDate DESC) rnum from `mother-216719.PROPERTY.ATTOM_DETAIL`
) Select * from cte where rnum = 1
```

Of note, there's 240 columns in this table.

This has been running over an hour, with no avail.
Is there a way to make this work?
Thanks!

Comment: Typically you would add an index on `(AATOM_ID, LastLoaddate)`, but alas, BigQuery does not support indices.  How many records does your table have?

Comment: 190 mil.  trying to short down to 130 or so.  Come to find out I have repetative records.

Comment: and historical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below approach - usually it helps

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY LastLoadDate DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `mother-216719.PROPERTY.ATTOM_DETAIL` t
GROUP BY ATTOM_ID
```